# Is there an analogous concept for De Rham cohomology in the framework of Clifford algebras?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, clifford-algebras, de-rham-cohomology, geometric-algebras

I’ve recently read about Clifford’s geometric algebra being [a more general framework for differential geometry than differential forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316766/are-clifford-algebras-and-differential-forms-equivalent-frameworks-for-different), simpler for the study of spaces with a metric tensor, and equivalent to the latter in some cases.

I’ve mostly learned about differential forms in the context of de Rham cohomology so I couldn’t help but asking myself if there’s an equivalent concept in the framework of Clifford algebras (I don’t know a whole lot about Clifford algebras yet so excuse me if this question doesn’t make sense).

Comment: In $\mathbb R^n$, I think up to sign, $\mathrm d$ is basically the same as what someone working with Clifford algebra might write as $\vec\nabla\wedge$. So I would imagine you could get the same basic de Rahm cohomology story in a slightly different language. But I don't have experience with actually doing this so can't write a full answer.